# Typescript "padStart" error when trying to push an object to an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I declare a object template which I populate with data:

```
   let dataTemplate = {
       publishedDate: "",
       Url: "",
       Title: "",
     }

     dataTemplate.publishedDate = xml.children[4].children[i].children[13].value;
     dataTemplate.Url = xml.children[4].children[i].children[16].value;
     dataTemplate.Title = xml.children[4].children[i].children[58].value;
```

I then declare a string array and try to push the above object to the array:

```
 let data: String[] = [];
 data.push(dataTemplate);
```

But I get a syntax error at "dataTemplate" at the following line:

```
data.push(dataTemplate);

[ts]
Argument of type '{ publishedDate: string; Url: string; Title: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'String'.
  Property 'padStart' is missing in type '{ publishedDate: string; Url: string; Title: string; }'.
```

How come? I use TS 3.3 and cannot uppgrade (MS SPFx does not have support for newer versions.

Comment: why are you trying to push object to string array? String array can contain only strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/**
 * First of all, define type for templateData
 */
type Template = {
    publishedDate: string;
    Url: string;
    Title: string;
}
let dataTemplate: Template = {
    publishedDate: "",
    Url: "",
    Title: "",
}

/**
 * Wrong. because TS expects array of string, and you are going to use here array of Template
 */
let data: String[] = [];// not ok

// Ok
let data1: Template[] = [];

 data1.push(dataTemplate); // works as expected
```